# IEnumerable <T> with anonymous methods

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I dont know how to get rid of this error ?

Error   1   Using the generic type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' requires 1 type arguments    C:\Users\huzaifa.gain\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\VendInvoiceImport\VendInvoiceImport\Program.cs  34  24  VendInvoiceImport

```
private static IEnumerable<string , string >  DistinctInvoiceNumber(DataTable   VendorInvoiceStagingTable)
       {
           var InvoiceLinecollection = VendorInvoiceStagingTable.AsEnumerable().Select(t => new {  number = t.Field<string>(VendInvoice.Number),LineNumber = t.Field<string>(VendInvoice.LineNumber)}).Distinct();
        return InvoiceLinecollection;
      }
```

[image]

Comment: Don't post inline images.  Post the offending code as text so it's readable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Linq query returns an sequence of anonymous type, but methods can't return anonymous types. You have several options:

- return an `IEnumerable<Tuple<string, string>>`

  ```
  private static IEnumerable<Tuple<string, string>>  DistinctInvoiceNumber(DataTable   VendorInvoiceStagingTable)
  {
      var InvoiceLinecollection = VendorInvoiceStagingTable
                                      .AsEnumerable()
                                      .Select(t => Tuple.Create(t.Field<string>(VendInvoice.Number), t.Field<string>(VendInvoice.LineNumber)))
                                       .Distinct();
      return InvoiceLinecollection;
  }
  ```
- return a `IDictionary<string, string>` as suggested in another answer (assuming your query doesn't return duplicate keys)

  ```
  private static IDictionary<string, string> DistinctInvoiceNumber(DataTable   VendorInvoiceStagingTable)
  {
      var InvoiceLinecollection = VendorInvoiceStagingTable
                                      .AsEnumerable()
                                      .Select(t => Tuple.Create(t.Field<string>(VendInvoice.Number), t.Field<string>(VendInvoice.LineNumber)))
                                      .Distinct()
                                      .ToDictionary(t => t.Item1, t => t.Item2);
      return InvoiceLinecollection;
  }
  ```
- create a class for this purpose with 2 string properties and return a sequence of that class

  ```
  private static IEnumerable<InvoiceLine>  DistinctInvoiceNumber(DataTable   VendorInvoiceStagingTable)
  {
      var InvoiceLinecollection = VendorInvoiceStagingTable
                                      .AsEnumerable()
                                      .Select(t => new InvoiceLine(t.Field<string>(VendInvoice.Number), t.Field<string>(VendInvoice.LineNumber)))
                                      .Distinct();
      return InvoiceLinecollection;
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Why you do not use `Dictionary<string, string>` instead?

```
private static Dictionary<string , string >  DistinctInvoiceNumber(DataTable   VendorInvoiceStagingTable)
       {
           var InvoiceLinecollection = VendorInvoiceStagingTable.AsEnumerable().Select(t => new {  number = t.Field<string>(VendInvoice.Number),LineNumber = 
                 t.Field<string>(VendInvoice.LineNumber)}).ToDictionary();
            return InvoiceLinecollection;
          }
```

Comment: Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,string>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: Then your return type should be Dictionary<string,string> or IDictionary<string,string>

Comment: edited, just should add ToDictionary at the end of LINQ expression.

Comment: Error 1 No overload for method 'ToDictionary' takes 0 What should go into todictionary Parameters